# C++ mingw32-make undefined references to library (Windows)

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw32, lib

instead of using large IDE's I wanted to try my first experiences with makefiles. Without knowing much about makefiles, I found an example and tried to adapt it to my project.
The makefile looks like this:

```
#This is an easier to use and modify makefile, but it is slightly more difficult to read than the simple one:
#
# 'make depend' uses makedepend to automatically generate dependencies 
#               (dependencies are added to end of Makefile)
# 'make'        build executable file 'mycc'
# 'make clean'  removes all .o and executable files
#

# define the C compiler to use

#CC = gcc
#CC = "C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe"
CXX = "C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe"

# define any compile-time flags
#CPPFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11

# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
#

#INCLUDES = -I/home/newhall/include  -I../include
INCLUDES = -IC:\Users\k0cke\Desktop\TestMake\ATCCalib\inc 

# define library paths in addition to /usr/lib
#   if I wanted to include libraries not in /usr/lib I'd specify
#   their path using -Lpath, something like:

#LFLAGS = -L/home/newhall/lib  -L../lib
LFLAGS = -LC:\Users\k0cke\Desktop\TestMake\ATCCalib\lib

# define any libraries to link into executable:
#   if I want to link in libraries (libx.so or libx.a) I use the -llibname 
#   option, something like (this will link in libmylib.so and libm.so:

#LIBS = -lmylib -lm
LIBS = -lvisa32

# define the C source files

#SRCS = emitter.c error.c init.c lexer.c main.c symbol.c parser.c
SRCS = main.cpp atcFlash.cpp measurements.cpp SerialCommunicationClass.cpp

# define the C object files 
#
# This uses Suffix Replacement within a macro:
#   $(name:string1=string2)
#         For each word in 'name' replace 'string1' with 'string2'
# Below we are replacing the suffix .c of all words in the macro SRCS
# with the .o suffix
#
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# define the executable file 

#MAIN = mycc
MAIN = apdCalib.exe

#
# The following part of the makefile is generic; it can be used to 
# build any executable just by changing the definitions above and by
# deleting dependencies appended to the file from 'make depend'
#

.PHONY: depend clean

all:    $(MAIN)
    @echo  Simple compiler named mycc has been compiled

$(MAIN): $(OBJS) 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

# this is a suffix replacement rule for building .o's from .c's
# it uses automatic variables $<: the name of the prerequisite of
# the rule(a .c file) and $@: the name of the target of the rule (a .o file) 
# (see the gnu make manual section about automatic variables)
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)

depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend needs it
```

I installed mingw to "C\MinGW\bin". In the folder "C:\Users\k0cke\Desktop\TestMake\ATCCalib", I have four .cpp source-files and "makefile". In "C:\Users\k0cke\Desktop\TestMake\ATCCalib\inc", I have 6 .h files. "visa.h" and "visatype.h" are the header files which should allow me to use the functions of the visa32.lib. "C:\Users\k0cke\Desktop\TestMake\ATCCalib\lib"contains the library "visa32.lib".

In the Windows cmd-window, I navigate to "C:\Users\k0cke\Desktop\TestMake\ATCCalib" and type mingw32-make.

Now I receive linker errors

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\k0cke\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPAAw9m.o:measurements.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `viOpenDefaultRM@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\k0cke\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPAAw9m.o:measurements.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `viOpen@20'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\k0cke\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPAAw9m.o:measurements.cpp:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `viGetAttribute@12'
.
.
.
```

In "measurements.cpp", I `#include "measurement.h"`. In "measurement.h", I `#include "visa.h"`and `#include "visatype.h"`

Do you have any suggestion what errors I could have made? I can't seem to find anything.

EDIT: Here are the build commands that are shown in the console:

```
"C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe" -Wall -g -std=c++11 -IC:\Users\k0cke\Desktop\TestMake\ATCCalib\inc  -o apdCalib.exe main.cpp atcFlash.cpp measurements.cpp SerialCommunicationClass.cpp -LC:\Users\k0cke\Desktop\TestMake\ATCCalib\lib -lvisa32
atcFlash.cpp: In function 'void atcFlash(serialCommunication&, std::string, std::string, std::string)':
atcFlash.cpp:23:6: warning: unused variable 'chooseSector' [-Wunused-variable]
   23 |  int chooseSector = 0;
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
atcFlash.cpp:24:6: warning: unused variable 'validSector' [-Wunused-variable]
   24 |  int validSector = 0;
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\k0cke\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLOPMRY.o: in function `Z9measureACiRdNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE':
C:\Users\k0cke\Desktop\TestMake\ATCCalib/measurements.cpp:12: undefined reference to `viOpenDefaultRM@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\k0cke\Desktop\TestMake\ATCCalib/measurements.cpp:21: undefined reference to `viOpen@20'
.
.
```

Comment: Hi @TedLyngmo, are you talking about the error codes? The complete compiler and linker commands are in the makefile-code.

Comment: Alright, I added the commands.

Comment: Ok good. If you look in `visa.h`, are all the functions enclosed like this `#ifdef __cplusplus` `extern "C" {` `#endif` ... _all functions_ ... `#ifdef __cplusplus` `}` `#endif` ?

Comment: Yes, at the start of the file it says `#if defined(__cplusplus) || defined(__cplusplus__)
   extern "C" {
#endif` and at the very end it says `#if defined(__cplusplus) || defined(__cplusplus__)
   }
#endif`

Comment: Ok, that's not it then. Are you using the 32 bit compiler? Perhaps you could add the compiler option `-m32` or specifying the compiler as `mingw32-g++` to rule out that it tries building a 64 bit executable?

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the makefile, I changed the line to `CXX = "C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-g++.exe"`. The linker errors still remain, though.

Comment: Ok, then I'm fresh out of ideas unfortunately. I hope the added info may help someone who knows this better.

Comment: Is there any way to check if mingw23 actually finds the linker? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: `ld.exe` is the linker and it's the one producing the `undefined reference to ...` lines unfortunately.

Comment: I reinstalled mingw but it still does not work and throws the same errors.

Comment: Have you tried using Visual Studio and its compiler?

Comment: Not yet, I could try that

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be easier. It's pretty common to get similar questions as yours from people using mingw. I don't know why that is since I've never used it myself. You could also install WSL2 + Ubuntu 20.04 in Windows nowadays. I use it myself and it gives a pretty good linux-like feeling, so your build scripts / makefiles etc. should work fine.

Comment: It is super weird. On my computer at work(also Windows 10) it works fine under STM32CubeIDE(like Eclipse) and also as a makefile. Here at home, it neither works with the IDE nor the makefile. I'd really like to know what exactly the linker is doing differently.

Comment: Odd indeed. :-(

Comment: I'm super confused, same errors occur while building under Debian10. I guess I will need to try another compiler?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's even possible, but did you use mingw there too?

Comment: Yes I did, because I need to compile it for Windows. But I found a solution now... Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Nice! Perhaps you can write an answer to your question so others can benefit from it too?

Answer (score 1):

Super weird answer: So the library named "visa32.lib" is used to interchange commands with measuring tools from Keysight to for example include it into an automatic measuring system. I installed the so called "Agilent Libraries Suite". From there, I took the library "visa32.lib". After everything I tried I thought that maybe the lib is somehow corrupted. After a search on my PC I found out that 5 libraries with the exact same name are provided by Agilent Libraries Suite. I tried every single one of them and found out that exactly ONE of it is working... So, problem solved, I guess.